# Why is it valid to assign <nil> to an interface type in Go?

Tags: go

http://play.golang.org/p/_GP3RZTh4Q

```
package main

import "fmt"

type TesterInterface interface{
    Yell()
}

type Tester struct{}

func (t Tester) Yell() {
    fmt.Println("HELLO")
}

func main() {
    var t TesterInterface
    t = Tester{}
    t.Yell()
    t = nil
    t.Yell()
}
```

I would expect the compiler to complain about line 19 (`t = nil`), since `nil` doesn't implement `Yell()`, however the program runs and provides the following output:

```
HELLO
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal 0xb code=0xffffffff addr=0x0 pc=0x201a9]

goroutine 1 [running]:
runtime.panic(0xef060, 0x1b3d44)
    /tmp/sandbox/go/src/pkg/runtime/panic.c:266 +0xe0
runtime.panicstring(0x1b3d44, 0x1b85)
    /tmp/sandbox/go/src/pkg/runtime/panic.c:489 +0x120
runtime.sigpanic()
    /tmp/sandbox/go/src/pkg/runtime/os_nacl.c:254 +0x80
main.main()
    /tmpfs/gosandbox-229cdcdf_329829af_705be907_f12cf4dc_ed51e32e/prog.go:20 +0xa9
runtime.main()
    /tmp/sandbox/go/src/pkg/runtime/proc.c:220 +0x1c0
runtime.goexit()
    /tmp/sandbox/go/src/pkg/runtime/proc.c:1394

goroutine 2 [syscall]:
runtime.notetsleepg(0xfeefdf88, 0x0, 0xf8475800, 0xd)
    /tmp/sandbox/go/src/pkg/runtime/lock_sema.c:254 +0xa0
runtime.MHeap_Scavenger()
    /tmp/sandbox/go/src/pkg/runtime/mheap.c:463 +0xc0
runtime.goexit()
    /tmp/sandbox/go/src/pkg/runtime/proc.c:1394
created by runtime.main
    /tmp/sandbox/go/src/pkg/runtime/proc.c:179
 [process exited with non-zero status]

Program exited.
```

Why does the compiler consider it legal to assign `nil` to an interface?

Additionally, from the [Go-docs:](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Interface_types)

> A variable of interface type can store a value of any type with a method set that is any superset of the interface.

How does "nil" contain a method set that is a superset of `TesterInterface`?  The docs go on to say that

> The value of an uninitialized variable of interface type is nil.

But this seems to contradict the first statement.

Comment: "can store", not "must store". It can also not store a value of any type.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is always dicey when you ask questions like "why does the compiler consider it legal…" The answer, as usual, is because that's the language, and every interface accepts the `nil` value. But there are more sides of this: the implementation of interfaces, and how Go would work if it were not this way.

Starting with the latter, consider the problem if `nil` were not a legal value for interfaces. How would you replace the common idiom:

```
func Something() error {
    ...
    return nil
}
```

This relies on the fact that `nil` is a valid `error`. <strike>Similarly, it is very common that pointers satisfy an interface. If `nil` did not also satisfy the interface, how would you return the `nil` pointer? Remember, `nil` is just a value.</strike>

To the implementation, see [Why is my nil error value not equal to nil?](http://golang.org/doc/faq#nil_error) The key point is that an interface is made up of a tuple of type and value, and for every interface, the tuple `(nil, nil)` is valid.

<strike>I assume you agree that a "typed `nil`" (i.e. a `nil` of some specific pointer type) should be assignable to an interface that is implemented by its pointer type, correct? So interfaces must be treated as though they could be `nil`, and you must `nil`-check them in exactly the same ways that you `nil`-check pointers. So there is no safety benefit to excluding the untyped `nil`, but you'd break many useful things you can do with interfaces (like return "no error").</strike>

(There's a slight subtlty to this last part. Read carefully again "Why is my nil error value not equal to nil?" and you'll realize that you can't trivially nil-check an interface that holds a typed nil value. You can only do that by type asserting the interface into its underlying pointer type or using reflect on it. This doesn't dramatically change the point, but I didn't want to gloss over that problem.)

---

**EDIT**

Based on @newacct's comments below, struck some extraneous points.

PeterSO's answer is also very important. Every type must have a zero value. What else would the zero value for an interface be but `nil`?

Comment: I don't follow your reasoning for why there needs to be `nil` interface. "how would you return the nil pointer?" You would just return the `nil` pointer. As you mentioned, they're different. "So interfaces must be treated as though they could be nil" No. The so-called "typed nil" is just a value of the underlying type, which the interface doesn't know about nor cares about.

Comment: @newacct, I agree. Edited.

Answer (score 8):

> [The Go Programming Language Specification](http://golang.org/ref/spec)
>
> [The zero value](http://golang.org/ref/spec#The_zero_value)
>
> When memory is allocated to store a value, either through a
>   declaration or a call of make or new, and no explicit initialization
>   is provided, the memory is given a default initialization. Each
>   element of such a value is set to the zero value for its type: false
>   for booleans, 0 for integers, 0.0 for floats, "" for strings, and nil
>   for pointers, functions, interfaces, slices, channels, and maps.

The value `nil` is valid for an interface type variable because it's the zero value for the interface type.

The [Go Data Structures: Interfaces](http://research.swtch.com/interfaces) article describes the implementation of interface values.